# I want to update my array's object. on button click

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

This is my App.js

How I change my array's object when click on button called "changer" and add newArr called "absent"

```
function App() {
  const [tables, setTables] = useState([
    { no: '1', name: 'Zameer', period: "Urdu" },
    { no: '2', name: 'Zaka', period: "English" }
  ])
  const changer = () => {
    setTables([...tables, { newArr: 'absent' }])
    
  }
const newArray = setTables



  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Tablee tables={tables} newArray ={newArray} />
      <Button onClick={changer} >absent</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my tablee.jsx component
How I change my array's object when click on button called "changer" and add newArr called "absent"
Please Help me out

```
const table = ({ tables, newArray }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Period</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        tables.map((table) => (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{table.no}</td>
                                <td>{table.name}{table.newArray} </td>
                                <td>{table.period}</td>
                            </tr>

                        ))
                    }

                </tbody>
            </Table></>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with this but if you just want to add a new row on button click and print "newArr" value, you need to modify this line:

```
<td>{table.name}{table.newArray} </td>
```

to

```
<td>{table.name}{table.newArr} </td>
```

Working code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-sun-cnlu3w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Actually, I want to change 'name object ' on button click in taht array

Comment: You want to add a new object in tables array?

Comment: no , I want to change name in that array

Comment: For that, you need to decide based in what property you want to change existing array and then create a new array using map. For eg, I changed based on property no here :
https://codesandbox.io/s/async-feather-y3s9dq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. actually am newbie so I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You overcomplicated this

```
function App() {
  const [tables, setTables] = useState([
    { no: '1', name: 'Zameer', period: "Urdu" },
    { no: '2', name: 'Zaka', period: "English" }
  ])
  const changer = () => {
    setTables([...tables, { no: tables.length, name: 'absent' }])
  }

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Tablee tables={tables} newArray ={newArray} />
      <Button onClick={changer} >absent</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```